# Fancybox cross-domain call

Tags: jquery, fancybox, cross-domain

I want to use fancybox popups in a webpage by cross-domain call. So i have inserted a js line in header that does all the dirty work. That means that this is responsible to call jQuery if it is not loaded, call fancybox.js and its css. Also it encloses the function to trigger popups. I have tried to call the important files i need in specific row. So i call popup after fancybox is properly brought to action like below:

```
    jQuery.getScript(
        "http://www.somedomain.com/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.3",
        function(){
           jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox();
        }
    );
```

The issue is that i get these error messages from firebug:

1.Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function for the first line of code in fancybox.js

2.Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox' when i call fancybox as you can see in my code below.

I have uploaded a demo of my code here [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fakiolinho/r6BgS/5/) (which are the html file and the remote js script the head's js link calls). Thank you very much.

Comment: what do you understand for `cross-browser call`? ... what is the question by the way?

Comment: I am trying to bring fancybox js and css from another server in the webpage that user visits. But it seems that the way and the row i bring them and jquery into action is not the right one. So i have written above the errors i have, just in case they could help you. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just have the fancybox plugin & css on YOUR site and load the other site's content into the fancybox in an iframe.

Comment: Thats a point of view but i dont want to include any other js code except for the js link to my server's js script, in other site's content.